# Combining code that relies on different transaction isolation levels in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I have two functions which both require a transaction. One is calling the other. I have code that can nest such transactions using SAVEPOINT into a single one.

If they have the same transaction isolation level there is no problem. Now, if they do not, is there still way I could 'correctly' combine the transactions?

What would be the risk, other than decreased performance, if I ran both transaction under the most restrictive isolation level of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, yes, generally you can combine transaction into the more restrictive isolation level.

The risk is pretty much that higher isolation level is going to catch more serialisation errors (i.e. `ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update` in REPEATABLE READ and `ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions` in SERIALIZABLE). The typical way to handle these serialisation failures is to retry the transactions, but you should verify whether this makes sense within the context of your application.

Another possible error that might occur is dead locks. Postgres should detect these and break the dead lock (after which the failing transaction should retry), but if you can, you should always try to write your application so dead locks can't exists in the first place. Generally, the main technique to avoid dead lock is to make sure that all applications that acquires any locks (implicit or explicit locks) to acquire those locks in consistent order.

You may need to take special care if your application needs to make requests to another external service, as you may need to verify whether the retry are going to cause you to make unwanted duplicate requests, especially if these external requests are not idempotent.